# Load files in subdirectories in PHP

Tags: php, html, static

I have a basic semi-static website written in PHP.  In the root folder I have a file called `posts.php` and also a folder called `posts`, in which there are `post1.php`, `post2.php`, and so forth and so on.

the `posts.php` file is in the root folder. When opened it creates a list from the files inside the `posts` folder and links to them.

In essence, what I want to do is to open php pages that I create statically and store in the posts/ folder in the browser.

The problem is that when I try to open these posts I am unable to. I can hard-link to them, and this "works", but if I do so my base templating will not work.

When I click links I go from one page to the next, and the URL shows `?p=index` or `?p=posts`. `post1.php` should be in something like `?p=posts/post1`, but it doesn't work.

There may be a problem in naming, since there is a folder and a php file with the same name (posts), but I'm not sure if that's it, nor how to work around it.

**edit**: Below are parts of the code that I believe pertain to this problem:

my index.php

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
require_once('header.php');
load_page();
// require_once('init.php');
require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

My header.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta charset="utf8">
<title>Paulo RSS Alves</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
       <!-- these are working without any issue -->
      <h1><a href='?p=index'>Paulo RSS Alves</a></h1>
    <div class="bar">
      <p><a href="?p=posts" class="link">Posts</a></p>
    </div>
```

posts.php:

```
<?php 
$dir = scandir('./post');
foreach ($dir as $file)
{
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    if ($path_parts['extension'] == 'php' and ctype_alpha($file[0])){
        // the purpose of this code is to only consider files with 
        // the .php extension and to remove that extension from the url.
        $file_f = str_replace('.'.$path_parts['extension'],  "", $file);
        echo '<li><a href='.'post/'.$file_f.'>'.$file_f.'</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

and functions.php:

```
<?php
function load_page() {
    (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $page = $_GET['p'] : $page = 'index';
    if (file_exists($page) && $page != 'index'){
        require_once($page);
    } else{
        require_once('init.php');
    }
}
?>
```

init.php is merely a welcome screen.

and a schema of my filetree:

```
 index.php

 init.php

 header.php

 footer.php

 functions.php

 posts.php

 posts/
   post1.php

   post2.php
```

Comment: I think you will get some help if you show us the actual code, as your description is not really making everything clear

Comment: @RiggsFolly done.

Comment: `require_once('./posts/'.$page);` You are not requiring from the posts folder I dont think

Answer (score 1):

You are not requiring from the posts folder

```
<?php
function load_page() {
    $dir = './posts/';

    (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $page = $_GET['p'] : $page = 'index';
    if (file_exists($page) && $page != 'index'){
        require_once($dir . $page);
    // add directory ^^^^
    } else{
        require_once('init.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So here's a funny thing: I tried doing this and it wasn't it. Since it is very small, I decided to rewrite the program. Most of the code I copied from here (I only changed HTML stuff). It worked. Interestingly enough, I think it may not have been related to PHP -- I found out that my Apache was conflicting with a deprecated Nginx install which was hindering me from updating files. I'm not sure if that was it, and it doesn't seem like it, but for some reason it's now working and I've barely changed anything.

Comment: (though I have changed this line in `posts.php`:

`echo '<li><a href=?p=posts/'.$file_f.'>'.$file_f.'</a></li><br>';`